# finding max value in python list of dicts

Tags: python

i have a python data structure as below:

```
[
    {
    'Transactions':{'value':301.0},
    'Users':{'value':21234.0},
    'key':u'18-24',
    'doc_count':30
    },
    {
    'Transactions':{'value':665.0},
    'Users':{'value':36053.0},
    'key':u'25-34',
    'doc_count':30
    },
    {
    'Transactions':{'value':452.0},
    'Users':{'value':20244.0},
    'key':u'35-44',
    'doc_count':30
    },
    {
    'Transactions':{'value':159.0},
    'Users':{'value':8316.0},
    'key':u'45-54',
    'doc_count':30
    },
    {
    'Transactions':{'value':119.0},
    'Users':{'value':5560.0},
    'key':u'55-64',
    'doc_count':30
    },
    {
    'Transactions':{'value':93.0},
    'Users':{'value':4168.0},
    'key':u'65+',
    'doc_count':30
    }
]
```

i want to find which `key` gives has max value of `Transactions` and which key has max value of Users. i am looking for a solution which is pythonic yet readable

Comment: there are too many questions asking the same thing, so closed, for your particular example: `max(ld,key=lambda d:d['Transactions']['value'])` will do

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre how does this works?plase explain a little

Comment: Have you checked on the duplicate link? I'm sure you'll find answers here.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre thanks i understand it now :)